# Is there a single word that means 'digital illustration'?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I am looking for a single word that means "digital graphics/artwork".

The most fitting word that I have been able to find is *illustrate*. As in

> "Bill creates illustrations."

However, illustrate does not in any way imply that the work being done is digital. So currently I am at *digital illustration*. As in

> "Bill creates digital illustrations."

Is there a single word that means 'digital illustration'?

Comment: digitalistrations? (hopefully a joke!)

Comment: Bill creates *content*? This may need to be set in some appropriate context, though.

Comment: Related at [graphicdeisgn.se](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/94013/15344)

Comment: I've heard the word _graphics_ used for digital illustrations (as opposed to physical). I do realise it's not unambiguous though. Anyway, most of your post is about the illustrations themselves, while the first sentence is about "to design ...". You may want to edit that.

Comment: Before seeing JonMark's digitalistrations, I was about to suggest digistration.

Having worked in traditional and digital publishing for about a generation, I promise you will not find an extant word. You will have to make one up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to be proved wrong, but I'm not sure there's a simpler form than *digital illustrations*, or even *digital artwork*. Some nouns are just too vague without qualifying adjectives. For instance:

> "Bill is a painter."

Does Bill paint houses? Cars? Aircraft? Bridges? Or does he dab at a canvas with oils and brushes? Or watercolours?

Comment: If your answer is you're not sure there's an answer, I'm not sure this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bill makes/does/creates CGI (computer-generated imagery).

This covers moving and still images, I'm not sure if there is a term that exists to distinguish between the two types.

Comment: I would have to agree with this one...  
From my experience, CGI **does** cover both moving (e.g. like what you create with [Art Of Illusion](http://www.artofillusion.org/))  and still images (e.g. like what you find at sites like [DigitalBlasphemy](http://www.digitalblasphemy.com/)). 
The thing is; If you can create a digital moving graphic with some piece of software, you can also create a still-image graphic, as well.

Comment: But an illustration can exist in digital form without having been *generated* by a computer.

Answer (score -1):

If the graphics are 3D, the word I would go for is [**model**.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/model)

Comment: "Bill creates models" doesn't sound very digital.

Comment: It doesn't even necessarily mean graphical models.

Comment: @ChrisH: Fun fact, "[graphical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_model)" doesn't even mean graphical model.

Comment: @Rahul good point, though in other fields it does.  I think we've established that *model* is too broad.

Answer (score -4):

It can be: Bill is good at creating virtualizations or simply Bill creates virtualizations

Comment: A "virtualization" is not a "digital illustration", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization